# Can I use all Yoga features on Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: lenovo, tablet

I mean those (*) gestures are available on Windows 10 with touchscreen, or any tablet mode when I use my laptop as tablet, etc...

(*)

- Auto switch to tablet mode.
- Disable the keyboard and touchpad on tablet mode.
- Handle back and next touchscreen gestures when I use the internet.
- Zoom with two fingers on images/webpages
- larger icons on tablet mode

Comment: Which are "those" features?

Comment: Auto switch to tablet mode. Disable the keyboard and touchpad on tablet mode. Handle back and next touchscreen gestures when I use the internet. Zoom with two fingers on images/webpages... larger icons on tablet mode... (Sorry about my poor english)

Comment: @tixovoxi please add those things to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Firefox, it implements its multi-touch support the same whether on Microsoft Windows or on Linux. The functionality of individual application programs is not actually linked to the OS they're built for.

The system shell in Micrsoft Windows 10 offers a different set of multi-touch gestures than does the Unity 7 shell on Ubuntu.  They're different application programs and do things differently.