# Can I make my keyboard disable / enter tablet mode when folding back my display?

Tags: keyboard, tablet, toshiba-satellite

I have a laptop with a fold back display (Toshiba Satellite P50W). When I fold it all the way back it acts more like a tablet, however the keyboard is still active an easy to bump keys on.

I'm pretty sure these laptops have a sensor on the hinge so they can tell they are folded back and cause the keyboard to disable / go into tablet mode. This doesn't appear to work in Ubuntu. I haven't been able to find where such a sensor would be in Linux (doesn't seem to show up in the ACPI code, or in dmesg).

Does anyone know how to get it to work in Ubuntu?

Comment: The Lenovo Yoga line also has a similar hinge and appears not to be currently supported - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/812508/can-i-use-all-yoga-features-on-linux-ubuntu

Comment: The first step is to run `acpi_listen` to see if a signal is sent when your laptop is morphed into a tablet. After that it's straight forward to disable keyboard and reenable when it morphs back from tablet to laptop.

Comment: I had tried acpi_listen and I don't seem to get any event.

Comment: Do you get events listed for lid close and open, ie suspend & resume?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure if the events go over some other bus or there needs to be kernel support for this event (or even if it doesn't exist at all?)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, could you post the solution for those who do get a signal using `acpi_listen`?  I get `PNP0C14:02 000000d0 00000000` on my Yoga 910 when I rotate the screen, and I'd like to disable the keyboard.

Comment: @MBWD I've put this on my to-do list but I'm incredibly busy with 20 hours overtime at work / week and looking for a new apartment. After September Labor Day long week-end I hope I can post an answer.

Comment: This sensor started working when I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 using GNOME. Not sure what component made it work..

Answer (score 1):

I have the following script to disable my laptop keyboard (as a file in ~/.local/bin/disable_laptop_keyboard)

```
#!/bin/bash
KeyboardID=`xinput --list | grep "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" | sed 's/[^=]*=\([1-9]*\).*/\1/'`
sudo xinput set-int-prop $KeyboardID "Device Enabled" 8 0
```

And then I have a similar enable_laptop_keyboard file where the only difference is that it says `8 1` instead of `8 0` on the last line.

You will just have to figure out which string identifies the keyboard that you want to disable. In my case it is "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard". If you first run `xinput --list | grep keyboard` you should be able to find out what your keyboard is called.

Comment: I wrote a small Python script to replace the bash script. It also disables the touchpad. https://github.com/tagadvance/toggle-tablet-mode